# postgresql create bitset from query by primary key

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a big table with primary autoincrement key. Sometimes i need to build bitmask for current filtering query on this table(which rows suit for my query). I can build mask in postgres or in my application. if i build mask in my app, it is necessary to fetch million rows from database, it is not fast. I can build mask in postgres using string_agg with 1 and 0, and fetch in app one row with one big column, it works and faster than previous case.
But It is not looks like best solution.

PS May be problem in fetching of million rows(I use jdbc)? Or may be exists some constraints in fetching from postgres? Can postgres archive data when send it to connection?

Comment: May I suggest to post this question on dba.stackexchange.com?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the table(s) in question, the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**.  [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Ideally also some sample data and the expected output based on that data.